# Storing/Retrieving/Editing project specific data with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm new to Django and I'm working on the public website for a small company.
I'm facing an issue that I guess has already been encountered by lots a django noobs, 
but I can't manage to find a good solution.
My problem is that there some informations (contact address, office phone number, company description...) that I use in nearly all of my views and are by nature unique (undertand: a database table with only 1 row). I currently store these informations has a model in my databse, but I find it a bit weird issue an additional database request each time (each view)
I need to access them. However, I need my client to be able to edit these informations (by the admin interface).
So, please, is there a django idiom to handle such an use case ?
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into caching solutions, they will probably do what you need.

The general queryset caching solution I use in johnny-cache, but for what you need, you can probably just load it up from the db and store it in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use select_related('contact_profile','office_data') etc when you query the items in your view, and in the admin, instead of registering all the data separately just use the InlineAdmin class for the Admin site and you will be able to edit all the information as if it was a single entity.

Check out the django docs for more information.